# Show that the following set is dense in $L^1 (\Bbb R^d)$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $E \subset \Bbb R^d$ such that $m(E)=0$ and $f : E \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous. Is the space of all integrable continuous functions $F :\Bbb R^d \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ with $F|_E =f$ dense in $L^1 (\Bbb R^d)$?

How can I proceed to tackle this problem? Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: No. You can find a counterexample by letting $E=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Would you please be more explicit?

Comment: Sure. Given any continuous $f:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb R$, there is exactly **one** continuous $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ for which $F|_E=f$. Namely, $F(x)=\lim_n f(q_n)$, where $q_n$ is a sequence of rationals converging to $x$. Therefore, the set of such $F$ is certainly not dense.

Comment: Actually, I should have said **at most one** instead of exactly one. For example, if $f(q)=1$ if $q^2<2$ and $f(q)=0$ if $q^2>2$, then $f$ is continuous, but does not have any continuous extensions $F$.

Comment: Oh! What a nice answer @Mike Earnest it is! Many many thanks to you for your help.

Comment: Please give it as an answer to my question. Then I will definitely accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, let $E=\mathbb Q$. Since any continuous function is determined by the values it takes on $\mathbb Q$, there will be at most one continuous extension of any $f:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb R$, so the set of such extensions is far from dense.